# Solana JSON RPC slower than @solana/web3.js?

Tags: jsonrpc-api

Has anyone else noticed that calls to the JSON RPC for solana seem to be not as current as calls to @solana/web3.js? The method I noticed this for was getProgramAccounts. When I create a new account and transfer it to program ownership, and then call getProgramAccounts, the @solana/web3.js getProgramAccounts method includes the new account in its response almost instantly, whereas for the JSON RPC call, it takes several calls for the new account to be in the response.

I'm pretty sure that the @solana/web3.js library uses the JSON RPC anyway, so I'm confused on why there is this difference. I am using the python requests library to make the call to the JSON RPC. Does anyone know why the JSON RPC seems to be not as current?

Comment: This sounds like a difference in confirmation levels (i.e. 'confirmed' in one setting, 'finalized' in the other). You would need to share code samples for us to further assist with this question and provide a real answer.